# Timezone offset is not considered with Calendar

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

I want to insert a timestamp column data into a MySQL column. The timezone of my location is GMT+3. Here is what I did to consider this timezone :

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone timeZone = now.getTimeZone();
int differenceUTCms = timeZone.getRawOffset();
int differenceHeureUTC = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(differenceUTCms)))));
now.setTime(new Date());
if (differenceUTCms <= 0) {
    now.add(Calendar.HOUR, Math.abs(differenceHeureUTC) + 3);
} else {
    now.add(Calendar.HOUR, Math.abs(3 - differenceHeureUTC));
}
query.setParameter(i, now.getTime());
```

But at runtime I still get 07:24:32 instead of 10:24:32 for the hours part ! So what is wrong ?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calender` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use for example `OffsetDateTime` and `ZoneId`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Do they work with Java 8 ?

Comment: Yes they do. They were exactly introduced in Java 8, so are built in.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the data type in MySQL is `timestamp`? (A MySQL `timestamp` is in UTC always.) What is `query`? Are you using Hibernate or another JPA implementation? We’d like to have a fuller picture of your setup, design and code.

Comment: yes the datatype is `timestamp`.
`query` is a native query : `javax.persistence.Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);`

Comment: Unrelated:  don’t use Strings to convert a `long` to an `int`.  Just write `int differenceHeureUTC = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(differenceUTCms);`

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, you can use OffsetDateTime:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_Connection.url, DB_Connection.user, DB_Connection.password);

Instant instant = Instant.now();

OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        
String update = "update schedule set timestamp = ? where id = 1";
try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(update)){
    preparedStatement.setObject(1, offsetDateTimeUTC);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

If you wanted it in UTC:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTimeUTC = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

=== Edited ===

If MySQL Does not support TimeStamp with Zone, you could get the time in UTC, and convert to LocateDateTime:

```
    Instant instant = Instant.now();

    OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    LocalDateTime timeStampInUTC = time.toLocalDateTime();

    System.out.println(timeStampInUTC); //2021-11-15T11:00:51.670151200
```

Comment: The JDBC specification says that the SQL timestamp type corresponds to a LocalDateTime.  OffsetDateTime would be appropriate for column of type TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE (which I don’t think MySQL supports).

Comment: @VGR The MySQL `timestamp` data type behaves like the `timestamp with time zone` in other systems in that it is always in UTC. I haven’t tried myself, but I think the driver is happy with an `OffsetDateTime` for such a column or value. Which definitely makes sense.